# Fetch caching response - no-cache headers not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, cache-control, fetch-api

I've been doing the [random quote machine](https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/build-a-random-quote-machine) project for freecodecamp and I can't seem to stop the response from the api being cached.

I've tried various answers:

- [fetch(), how do you make a non-cached request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246444/fetch-how-do-you-make-a-non-cached-request)
- https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/apis-and-the-random-quote-machine-not-even-sure-what-to-ask/65982/13

I thought I had it at one point:

```
fetch(this.url, {cache: 'no-cache'})
    .then(res => res.json())
```

... but I was just disabling the cache in developer tools.

Please help. :-D.

Here is where i've been trying to make it work:
https://codepen.io/JonathanDWood/pen/gRNNKx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to fix it by appending `Date.now()` to the url. I don't really like it as a permanent solution as it doesn't address the underlying caching issue but it works.

```
fetch(this.url+ Date.now(), {cache: 'no-store'})
    .then(res => res.json())
```

Comment: Directly appending a string may break the URL. Consider using a query string like https://stackoverflow.com/a/59493583 .

Comment: Yeah that's a great point