# Android - Make non-cached request

Tags: java, android, kotlin, httprequest

I am trying to fetch an uncached version of this url: https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/version.txt
or this url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vedantroy/image-test/master/version.txt 
in Android.

I thought I solved the problem in this post: [Fuel Android - Make non-cached request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477300/fuel-android-make-non-cached-request)
, but I'm still getting cached versions of those two URLs.

How can I fetch uncached versions of the file at those two URLs?

I'm open to using any Java or Kotlin library.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the content from cache because of the header of your last API call. You can change the `Control-Cache` header to control wheter you want to cache it or not.

For example with retrofit:

```
@GET("ws/exampleUrl")
Something getSomething(@Header("Cache-Control") String cacheControl);
```

and set the Cache-Control header to `no-cache` If you don't want to hold it:

```
myApi.getSomething(forceRefresh ? "no-cache" : null);
```