# why fetch cache mode and headers options are not working to get a fresh response?

Tags: javascript

I try to get a fresh list of data by invoking a url using fetch. This url return a json. Following the instructions described in these links [fetch(), how do you make a non-cached request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246444/fetch-how-do-you-make-a-non-cached-request) and https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/03/referrer-and-cache-control-apis-for-fetch/, I build the following init object.

```
const headers = new Headers();

headers.append('pragma', 'no-cache');
headers.append('cache-control', 'no-cache');

const init = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    cache: 'reload',
};
```

But after adding it as a second argument to fetch method the return data does not include the most recently added data, so I think it is due to cache.

The complete example is as follows

```
function getYears() {
    const id = getId();
    const request = new Request(`index.php?ep=name&id=${id}`);
    const headers = new Headers();

    headers.append('pragma', 'no-cache');
    headers.append('cache-control', 'no-cache');

    const init = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers,
        cache: 'reload',
    };

    fetch(request, init)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            window.yearCollection = years;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message);
        });
}
```

The logical flow is the following, when loading the page the method getYears () is invoked, then when sending data in a form, the page is reloaded. Here the list of years is not updated, I must refresh the page manually, to get the list with the updated data

Comment: Try changing your `cache: 'reload'` to `cache: 'no-store'` to prevent caching of results. Secondly, your PHP server may caching the page due to frequent hits to the same page.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but after setting cache mode to `'no-store'` I am getting the same result

Comment: And are you certain your PHP server isn't returning cached results either?