# How can I stop caching when using AJAX to read a file?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm currently building a website that uses AJAX to dynamically update sections of the page without the need to refresh, however, when I change aspects of the file that AJAX reads the website sometimes takes minutes to update even though the file is read about once per second. Whilst looking for the issue I found that I can turn caching off by using the developer tools and this then allowed the website to update at the appropriate speed.

Here's the code I am using:

```
var path = "Path of the json file i am reading"
var state;

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    state = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", path, true);
xhttp.send();
```

I've been looking for a while now and the only advice I can see about what to do about the cache is to use the developer tools to turn it off. Is there any way I can implement some code to automatically tell the browser to not cache the file being read?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246444/fetch-how-do-you-make-a-non-cached-request

Comment: This was a huge help thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch(), how do you make a non-cached request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246444/fetch-how-do-you-make-a-non-cached-request)