# How to bypass cache while using Fetch Method in advanced js

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

I have a application, which takes user inputs in a array, and for every element in the array I am calling my server using fetch, but result is displayed so quickly, it shows cached output, can you please suggest how I can bypass this http cache, while using fetch() method.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Look through the [`fetch` documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) You can find it yourself there

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246444/fetch-how-do-you-make-a-non-cached-request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch(), how do you make a non-cached request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246444/fetch-how-do-you-make-a-non-cached-request)

Answer (score -1):

Use this header => **Cache-Control: no-cache**

---

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

Comment: Or the English version here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control