On entity edit the old values are shown in modal
I am learning Vanilla JS and now Grid.js too. Currently using gridjs in my application's html like below:
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gridjs/dist/gridjs.umd.js"></script>

All works well but when I try to edit an entity the modal shows the values which were there when I loaded the page initially. The bootstrap modal doesn't show the new values even though the page shows the correct values.
The modal won't show the correct and updated values unless I clear the entire browser cache and restart the browser. The same can be replicated on all the (updated) browsers I have. Tried on - Brave, Chrome, Edge. I tried to find where this cache is stored and coming from but could not find anything relevant on https://gridjs.io/ too.
The entire js code and project code is on github and can be viewed using above links. I just tagged the grid.js as to me it appears to be the only correct tag. However I am using bootstrap5 and SpringBoot 3.x too in the application.
What could possibly the reason may be for this? And how can I avoid clearing cache every time? Any pointers/directions will be greatly appreciated.

How do you save/load values? If you use a json file or an xml file the browser save that files in cache and don't reload it from server, so the values are not updated.
In this case one solution is to add a param after file name like myfile.json?upd=12345. Everytime you change the param value you force the browser to reload the file from server and so update the values too.

I am loading the data in modal by making a fresh call to the end point and loading the same in the modal.

After edit the entity gets updated in the database (verified) and on html as well but the edit button brings back the old values of the entity. Not sure from where.

Never mind. It turned out to be fetch api issue.  This fixed my issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43968374/8534285. I learned this new thing today.
